# Como pasar datos de vue js con rutas Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

soy nuevo en Laravel+Vue Js y estoy estancado con un problema.

Tengo un componente llamado Articulo, que lee todos los datos provenientes de MySQL, lo cual realizo ese get a través de Axios.

```html
traerProductos(){
                let me=this;
                axios.get('/url').then(function(response){
                    me.arrayProductos = response.data
                    });
                })
            },
        }
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, el punto es que dentro de mi componente, al desplegar la lista de productos, tengo un atributo `<a href="#"></a>` donde pretendo a que me redireccione para ver el producto en detalle, es decir, que al hacer clic a ese hipervinculo pueda parametrizar el `id` de ese determinado producto y me redireccione a una nueva ventana para ver en detalle el producto.

```html
<div v-for="producto in arrayProductos" :key="producto.id">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Nombre Producto</th>
                        <th>Detalle</th>
                        <th>Eliminar</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{producto.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{producto.nombre}}</td>
                        <td><a href="">Ver detalles</a></td>
                        <td><button @click="quitarProducto()">Quitar</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
</div>
```

De momento no estoy utilizando Vue Router, porque desconozco completamente eso, sin embargo, la idea es poder usar el `producto.id` que genero en el v-for para enlistar los productos.
¿Hay una forma de parametrizar ese id que obtengo con Vue y usar las rutas de Laravel a través de Route('..., $xxx')? es una idea imposible? o puedo usar otro método ?

Comment: Se me ocurre que así como tienes la url en `axios.get('/url')`,  puedes hacer `<a :href="'/url/'+product.id">Ver detalles</a>`

Comment: hmm no me está sirviendo, no está enviando el id como parámetro, por lo que no lleva nada para realizar la consulta.

Comment: A lo que voy, es que si `product.id` vale `1`, tendrás un link así `<a href="/url/1">Ver detalles</a>`. Es un ejemplo genérico para una pregunta genérica. No entiendo a que te refieres con "no está enviando el id como parámetro, por lo que no lleva nada para realizar la consulta"... ¿qué parámetro? ¿qué debería llevar para realizar qué consulta?

Comment: un par de cosas. Vue no tiene nada que ver con laravel. Vue es tu front. Laravel es tu back, y aunque te los vendieron juntos, de front podrias tener react o nada, y de back cualquier otro. Luego, esto: let me=this; es totalmente innecesario en vue. Vue ya sabe el contexto. Y me uno a las consultas de porloscerros respecto de porque no te funciona algo asi...

Comment: ok ok entiendo, simplemente lo que necesito es que al darle clic a ver detalles me mande a los detalles en una nueva vista, ya sea un nuevo componente o una vista de laravel, posiblemente deba borrar.. no me expresé bien

Comment: Si no usas vue-router es un link normal, le pones en el href una url donde el backend (laravel en este caso) devuelva la página.

Comment: Entiendo, pero  `product.id` proviene del v-for que generé para enlistar los datos, si quiero usar laravel con route, debo enviar un parámetro para ver los detalles de ese producto en específico  `href="{{route('/miruta',$parametro)}}"` , entonces no sé como puedo enviar ese parametro si lo saco con vue

Comment: o no es necesario ?

Comment: El helper `route` de laravel sirve simplemente para generar urls a rutas con nombre, o sea, en `{{route('nombredemiruta',$parametro)}}`, si `$parametro` vale `1` es para generar algo así `http://midominio/uri-de-mi-ruta/1`. De todas maneras no puedes usar `route` de laravel pues estás en un componente vue, y tendrías que hacer algo como lo del primer comentario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes enviar el link como un enlace normal, la unica diferencia con vue-router es que este va ser asincrono a diferencia de un href normal, para acceder a la ruta debes generar el v-for asi

```
<div v-for="producto in arrayProductos" :key="producto.id">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Nombre Producto</th>
                        <th>Detalle</th>
                        <th>Eliminar</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{producto.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{producto.nombre}}</td>
                        <td><a :href="`/tu-ruta/${producto.id}`">Ver detalles</a></td>
                        <td><button @click="quitarProducto()">Quitar</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
</div>
```

debes crear una ruta en el archivo route y recibir el id, si quieres puedes hacer inyección de dependencias para obtener el modelo de forma automatica

Comment: Ok, lo probaré y te comento, ¿a qué te refieres con hacer inyección de dependencias ?

Comment: Probé lo que me mencionas y si me funciona, mi pregunta ahora va más allá de la funcionalidad. Si con vue-router es asíncrono, ¿es mala práctica estar usando las rutas de laravel para abrir una vista nueva sólo para traer los detalles, en este caso de un producto? Me gustaría aprender a usar vue-router, pero ya llevo algo avanzado con mi proyecto y no sé si deba realizar tantos cambios.

Comment: la verdad vue-router lo unico que va proporcionar al usuario es una mejor experiencia ya que no se va recargar la pagina pero si ya has avanzado con tu proyecto no le veo nada de malo a tener una vista nueva para el detalle del modelo, yo solo uso vue router cuando el proyecto esta separado back y front